# How to set a value at memory offset from a const void pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a pointer returned from a function

```
rs2::video_frame frame = frames.get_color_frame();
const void* data = frame.get_data();
```

I *know* that this pointer is an array of RGB values (i.e. 3 `char`s) of size `frame.get_data_size()`.

How can I modify certain pixel colors given that

```
int bpp = frame.get_bytes_per_pixel();
int width = frame.get_width();
int height = frame.get_height();

int offset = (y * width * bpp) + (x * bpp);
int r = offset;
int g = offset + 1;
int b = offset + 2;

// ?data[r] = newRed;
// ?data[g] = newGreen;
// ?data[b] = newBlue;
```

Comment: Cast it to a pointer of the pixel type, then use offsets. `void*` isn't something you can manipulate directly.

Comment: You need to case `data` to `char*` in order to dereference it.

Comment: @tadman I am aware of casting, and all. I have programmed in C/C++ a little, many years ago, but it's a question of **how**.

Comment: If you're back to programming C++ then it's time to brush up on the fundamentals. C and C++ have completely different approaches here, so don't confuse the two as C/C++ which is not a thing. Use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) for C++.

Comment: @tadman to give you an idea, last time I touched a compiler was on 386 using TurboC++ 3.5. A while back.

Comment: The good news is there's a lot of training material online that didn't exist in the mid 1990s. I'd recommend brushing up a bit or this will be an exercise fraught with nothing but frustration.

Comment: I've already suggested how: `static_cast<char*>`. Then manipulate it like a regular `char*` buffer.

Comment: what's the return type of `rs2::video_frame::get_data()` ? If it returns a `const void *`, then it's suggesting you shouldn't modify the pointed to value.

Comment: @Artefacto yes, the function returns a `const void *` and I do not want to cast that value. As I wrote, I know that the pointer returned is an array of `char`, and I want to directly modify a few values at that memory location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have it easier if you would have an object oriented approach:

```
struct Pixel {
    short red;
    short green;
    short blue;
};
```

Let your frame work with an `std::vector<Pixel> pixels`; which is returned by reference. `std::vector<Pixel>& get_data();`

```
pixels[y * width + x].red = newRed;
pixels[y * width + x].green = newGreen;
pixels[y * width + x].blue = newBlue;
```

If you really have to work with `void*` then try this

```
char* data = static_cast<char*>(const_cast<void*>(dataframe.get_data()));
// Since you also const cast it becomes more and more dangerous. You really need know what you are doing.

size_t bpp = frame.get_bytes_per_pixel();
size_t width = frame.get_width();
size_t height = frame.get_height();

size_t offset = (y * width * bpp) + (x * bpp);
size_t r = offset;
size_t g = offset + 1;
size_t b = offset + 2;

*(data + r) = newRed;
*(data + g) = newGreen;
*(data + b) = newBlue;
```

For bulk updates you can use `memset`.

See https://godbolt.org/z/xvc1xs for details.

Comment: you need to cast away the constness as well in order to write

Comment: FWIW `memset` worked! `memset((void *)data + r, (char) newRed, (size_t) 1);`

Comment: You are right, pointer needs to not `const` as I have it in my godbolt example. I correct this in the answer.

Your `memset` works because you cast the `const` away